# Correspondences in C* algebras

Tags: operator-algebras

I was wondering if anyone could tell me where to look for the use or history of C* correspondences. I have heard of `Connes C* correspondence', but cannot find a reference. Any other references would be gratefully received.

Classical correspondences arise when considering subsets of $X\times Y$ which generalise the graph of a function $f:X\to Y$. In noncommutative geometry they are some form of bimodule, just as the functions on the subsets above would be a $C(X)-C(Y)$ bimodule. As such they are used in KK-theory (well, the commuting algebra restrictions can be reduced to this). I am looking more at the historical development or other uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard of Connes' preprint but I have never seen it. There [this other one](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/popa-correspondences.pdf) by Popa, though.

Comment: Thanks! After a bit of follow up on that answer, it seems to be the best source available.